# Undetectable SD card

Tags: windows-8, sd-card

I've had some weird stuff going on with my phone SD card so I decided to format it. Right at the 100% of formatting the message box with "Windows can't format this drive" popped up. Now the card is not detected when inserted into a card reader and utilities like Disk Management and `diskpart` just hang when started. Mac OS doesn't detect it as well. Is there a way to repair it?

UPD: Tried using a Linux Live CD. By using a working SD card I found that the drive should be `/dev/sdc` but when the faulty card is inserted it is listed as "UNCLAIMED" by `lshw`

UPD2: `dmesg` output

```
[  234.219215] usb 2-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  244.475189] usb 2-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  260.731614] usb 2-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  260.979757] usb 2-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  271.231711] usb 2-4: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  271.365365] sd 11:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

Comment: Did you tried checking it with another computer? Did you try with your cellphone? Chances are that it died.

Comment: Phone doesn't detect it. As for dying, the card is pretty new and not heavily used, so it seems unlikely.

Comment: The manufacturing process is not perfect, and I've had many cards that are dead out-of-the-box (specially if they're pirated clones). Also, they're very fragile pieces of hardware. So believe me, it's likely indeed.

Comment: If I were you I would boot up with Linux Live CD and make some magic on the card with _gedit_ or/and _fdisk_. Sometimes it goes deeper and heals SD cards rather, I mean open source apps.

Comment: Try a quickformat.  There is a checkbox for that.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov I have some experience with Linux disk tools, the problem is that even the computer doesn't start (hangs when BIOS tries to detect available drives) when the card is inserted.

Comment: you don't need to have the card inserted right at the system start up. Put it later when your Linux is running. Did you put SD card in card reader and enabled it in BIOS? If so , there is nothing surprising that the computer hangs when the is inserted in some cases - when certain data is on there it can hang everything.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov any specifics on what I should do? The card doesn't show up in `gparted` (well, at least it doesn't hang)

Comment: yes, please run this command after you insert the card `dmesg| tail -20|less` and write here its output. Or, to write less, tell what device created (if any) after it is inserted. The name we would like to know at this step could be like, for example, `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/mmcblk0` - you say what you can see there.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov see update. it's listed as unclaimed and doesn't show up in `/dev`

Comment: what did `dmesg` say though?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov see update

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are not disk errors, they're USB errors. The disk is probably fine, it's a problem with (in order of likelihood) the USB cable, the USB connectors, the USB root port/hub, a broken USB device controller or a dodgy host controller.

Try a different cable in a different USB port and see if it makes a difference. Insert the plug quickly and firmly, don't wiggle it in and out slowly, as in my experience dodgy electrical contacts like that can produce this issue. You could also try plugging it in *before* connecting power to the disk, if it's a model with external power.

Someone form [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-5549075.html) had been fighting for many hours all week long and confirmed that was a mechanical/electrical issue - probably some lines were not contacted properly, - "Okay, sorted this out by taking the HD out and placing it in a new (well second-hand) caddy with a different USB controller. Problem Solved "

Comment: Other SD cards work fine, I've also tried different micro-SD adapters.

Comment: This confirms that the card is bad itself. They die from time to time.